# How to set up an Express route with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I am building a MEVN stack CRUD app (Vue, Node, Express, MongoDB). I am attempting to set up the following Express route for my app...

```
postRoutes.get('/view/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  let id = req.params.id;
  res.send(await collection.find({}).toArray());
  res.status(201).send();
});
```

...so that it returns specific data from MongoDB based on the id of that data. I am not sure how to set up `res.send` so that it finds data based on `req.params.id`. I tried passing in `req.params.id` like so...

```
postRoutes.get('/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  let id = req.params.id;
  res.send(await collection.find({ _id: mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.id)}).toArray());
  res.status(201).send();
});
```

...but that also did not work. Any idea how to set up this route so that it finds data based on the ID parameter? Thanks!

My full Express router page is below:

```
const express = require('express');
const postRoutes = express.Router();
const mongodb = require('mongodb')


postRoutes.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  res.send(await collection.find({}).toArray());
});


postRoutes.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  let task = req.body;
  await collection.insertOne(task);
  res.status(201).send();
});

postRoutes.get('/view/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  let id = req.params.id;
  res.send(await collection.find({}).toArray());
  res.status(201).send();
});

postRoutes.delete('/delete/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  collection.deleteOne({ _id: mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.id) });
  res.status(200).send({});
});

async function loadPostsCollection() {
  const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(
    '...',
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }
  );
  return client.db("test").collection("todos")
}

module.exports = postRoutes;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not work"? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Meaning, passing in ```{ _id: mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.id)}``` to the ```collection.find()``` does not succeed in returning specific data from MongoDB based on the id of that data. In other words, the specific data requested in the call is not being returned as a response from the Express route.

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 are you getting complete data of that collection in both cases?

Comment: Yes, I am getting complete data by running ```res.send(await collection.find({}).toArray());```, but I want to configure that same response in the ```/view/:id``` route so that it returns only data specific to that ID parameter.

Comment: Try logging ```mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.id)``` before sending to filter.

Comment: I ran that in the console. The data of the targeted ID returns to the console. However,  ```res.send()``` still does not return the data in a response to the front end. I'm not seeing the data rendering on my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had better to use `findOne` method like this:

```js
const { ObjectID } = require("mongodb");

postRoutes.get("/view/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  let id = req.params.id;

  let result = await collection.findOne({
    _id: new ObjectID(id)
  });

  if (!result) {
    return res.status(400).send("Not found");
  }

  res.status(200).send(result);
});
```

Comment: would you be willing to look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537526/how-to-set-up-an-update-route-in-express

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the filter in find query i.e

```
postRoutes.get('/view/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  let id = req.params.id;
  const o_id = new mongo.ObjectID(id);
  const result=await collection.find({ id: o_id });
  res.status(201).send(result.toArray());
});
```

Also you can't send the response twice for one request so omit one `resp.send()`.

Comment: This makes sense, but it still send a response to the frontend. Meanwhile, the data now doesn't return to the console.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement bit more?

Answer (score 0):

If you require a specific data from the DB so you need use **findById** method and pass your  id instead of **find** method :

```
postRoutes.get('/edit/:id', async (req, res) => { const collection = await loadPostsCollection(); let id = req.params.id; res.send(await collection.findById(id).toArray()); res.status(201).send(); });

postRoutes.get('/view/:id', async (req, res) => { const collection = await loadPostsCollection(); let id = req.params.id; res.send(await collection.findById(id).toArray()); res.status(201).send(); }); 

postRoutes.delete('/delete/:id', async (req, res, next) => { const collection = await loadPostsCollection(); collection.deleteOne({ _id:req.params.id}); res.status(200).send({}); });
```