# How to set up an update route in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I am building a MEVN stack CRUD app (Vue, Node, Express, MongoDB). I am attempting to set up the following Express route for my app...

```
postRoutes.post('/update/:id', async(req, res)=> {
    const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
    let id = req.params.id;
    let result = await collection.findOne(req.params.id)
    if (!result) {
      res.status(404).send("data is not found");
    }
    else {
        result.title = req.body.title;
        result.body = req.body.body;
        result.updateOne();
    }
});
```

..in order to update specific data based on the id of that data. After clicking the update button on the front end and triggering an `updatePost()` method...

```
    updatePost() {
      let uri = `http://localhost:4000/posts/update/${this.$route.params.id}`;
      this.axios.post(uri, {
        title: this.post.title,
        body: this.post.body
      }).then(() => {
        this.$router.push({name: 'posts'});
      });
    }
```

...the express route above does not execute. I also tried configuring the route like so...

```
postRoutes.post('/update/:id', async(req, res)=> {
    const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
    let id = req.params.id;
    let result = await collection.findOne({
      _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)
    });
    if (!result) {
      res.status(404).send("data is not found");
    }
    else {
        result.title = req.body.title;
        result.body = req.body.body;
        result.updateOne();
    }
});
```

But this also did not work. Any idea how to set up an update route?

Here are all of my routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const postRoutes = express.Router();
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

postRoutes.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  res.send(await collection.find({}).toArray());
});

postRoutes.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  let task = req.body;
  await collection.insertOne(task);
  res.status(201).send();
});

postRoutes.get("/edit/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  let id = req.params.id;
  let result = await collection.findOne({
    _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)
  });
  if (!result) {
    return res.status(400).send("Not found");
  }
  res.status(200).send(result);
});

postRoutes.post('/update/:id', async(req, res)=> {
    const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
    let id = req.params.id;
    let result = await collection.findOne({
      _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)
    });
    // let result = await collection.findOne(req.params.id)
    if (!result) {
      res.status(404).send("data is not found");
    }
    else {
        result.title = req.body.title;
        result.body = req.body.body;
        result.updateOne();
    }
});

postRoutes.delete('/delete/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
  collection.deleteOne({ _id: mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.id) });
  res.status(200).send({});
});

async function loadPostsCollection() {
  const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(
    'mongodb+srv://jsfanatik:1qaz2wsx@cluster0-lv686.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }
  );
  return client.db("test").collection("todos")
}

module.exports = postRoutes;
```

Comment: You might start by adding some error handling.  You appear to have no error handling for any of your `await` statements.  Each route that uses `await` should be surrounded in a `try/catch` so you can catch any errors and log the error and send an error response.

Comment: What does "this also did not work" mean?  Does your client get an error?  Any errors logged on the server?  We expect you to do elemental debugging and to report what you did and what you observed since problems like this are not something that we can reproduce ourselves.  Does your `postRoutes.post('/update/:id',...)` route get called?  If so, how far into the body of the function does it get?  Where does it go wrong.

Comment: Can you show the code where you register the `postRoutes` router?

Comment: The console does not log an error, but it also does not redirect back to the the ```posts``` component after updating. I have checked that the ```updatePost()``` method is set up correctly.

Comment: As @jfriend00 said, it doesn't look like you registered the routes

Comment: I'm not sure how to register routes. Any recommendations on how to set that up?

Comment: What do you do with the exported `postRoutes`?  Are you doing a `require()` on that module file?  If so, please show us that code.  If not, that's at least part of your problem.  You would need `const postRoutes = require('./postroutes.js');   app.use("/posts", postRoutes)`.  This assumes the name of the file containing your post routes is `postroutes.js`. Since, it is likely named something differently, you fill in the appropriate name/path.  And Express router does nothing until it's hooked into the `app` object appropriately.

Comment: Where'd you go?  I'm trying to help, but not getting a response from you.

Comment: Can you add your main file (index, server or ap.js) to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You request URL is `/posts/update/:id` but I don't see that path in any express router.
You are missin /posts in your router

```js
postRoutes.post('/update/:id', async(req, res)=> {
    const collection = await loadPostsCollection();
    let id = req.params.id;
    let result = await collection.findOne(req.params.id)
    if (!result) {
      res.status(404).send("data is not found");
    }
    else {
        result.title = req.body.title;
        result.body = req.body.body;
        result.updateOne();
    }
});
```